# Lambda expression in Android Library Module not working

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-service

I had an android app module which used jdk 8 and enabled Jack Options. Then I convert it to an Android Library module. And then I have to remove Jack Options from build gradle. And now the Lambda expression gives me below error when I try to build the AAR file.

```
Error:(59, 25) error: cannot find symbol method metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)
```

The code giving this error is,

```
Runnable r= () -> {
      appManager.startApp(definition,identifier);
};
```

My Build Gradle is

```
Apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What is the reason for this problem?

Comment: Did you found a solution??

Comment: @chamthabeysinghe did you found the solution?

Answer (score 7):

On my machine I was missing the file `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/28.0.3/core-lambda-stubs.jar`, so I had to reinstall version 28.0.3 of the build tools using the Android Studio SDK manager.

(I had to check 'Show package details' to see the full list of build-tools versions)

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this! I'd never expect sdk could miss some files just like that.

Comment: Thank you so much man. You saved my life! I was struggling for more than a day wondering why this is happening! Re-installing build-tools solved the issue for me too.

Comment: how i install missing core-lamba-stub.jar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872961/flutter-project-error-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception , core-lamba-stubs.jar missing

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to apply the retro lambda plugin.

Add this line to your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary with Java 1.8 though, and Android docs specifically say not to use it if you're using Java 1.8