# "cannot find symbol method metafactory" using Lambda

Tags: android, lambda, java-8

I'm using `java 8` and `lambda` expressions. When I use lambda expressions with `OnClickListeners` everything is fine, but when I use that in this `animate` method:

```
public void configureFragmentToolbar(String title, boolean displayHomeAsUpEnabled) {
   //..
    this.toolbar.animate().translationY(-50).setDuration(300).withEndAction(() -> { //ERROR
        toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
    });
}
```

I´m getting this error:

> `"error: cannot find symbol method
>   metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)"`

**gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

def junitVersion = '4.12'
def mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
def daggerVersion = '2.5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':commons')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"

    apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
}
```

Can you tell me why I'm getting that error? Thank you

Comment: try build - clean project

Comment: I did build - clean project a lot, but still getting the error

Comment: this maybe is a hint for you https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/7

Comment: or maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452827/lambda-expression-in-android-library-module-not-working

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor How did you solved this, I am facing a similar problem?

Comment: having this problem. Idk what else to do.

Answer (score 4):

In `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/27.0.3/`, `missing the file : core-lambda-stubs.jar`. You just need reinstall the build tool.

Comment: how i install core-lamba-stub.jar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade android build tools to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```