# Bazel + Android + Java8 complains about non-referenced API level 13

Tags: android, java-8, bazel

UPDATED 202010130 to reflect a new minimum example, guava is not relevant.

TL:DR; When referencing the Java8 method `Collectors.of` in code intended for android `bazel build` for the app fails with an error message referring to "current API level 13" even though `minSdVersion=28` is specified.

I've created a [github repo](https://github.com/bdleitner/android_error_demo) to provide a minimal example to illustrate the problem (and the `README` there has some more details).

When the code includes a reference to `Collectors.of`, the following error occurs.

```
ERROR: C:/projects/bazel/android_error_demo/src/main/java/com/example1/bazel/BUILD:5:1: Dexing src/main/java/com/example1/bazel/_dx/greeter_activity/libgreeter_activity.jar_desugared.jar with applicable dexopts [] failed (Exit 1)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in com.example1.bazel.Dep.message:()Ljava/lang/String;: invoking a static interface method java.util.stream.Collector.of:(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;Ljava/util/funct
ion/BinaryOperator;Ljava/util/function/Function;[Ljava/util/stream/Collector$Characteristics;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector; strictly requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (blocked at current API level 13)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexBuilder.produceDexArchive(DexBuilder.java:255)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexBuilder.processRequest(DexBuilder.java:220)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexBuilder.runPersistentWorker(DexBuilder.java:173)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexBuilder.main(DexBuilder.java:121)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in com.example1.bazel.Dep.message:()Ljava/lang/String;: invoking a static interface method java.util.stream.Collector.of:(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;Ljava/util/function/BinaryOperator;Ljava/util/
function/Function;[Ljava/util/stream/Collector$Characteristics;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector; strictly requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (blocked at current API level 13)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.fail(Simulator.java:947)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.checkInvokeInterfaceSupported(Simulator.java:917)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.access$500(Simulator.java:43)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitConstant(Simulator.java:687)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:764)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:117)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:789)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:744)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:309)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:150)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:102)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.Dexing.addToDexFile(Dexing.java:219)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexConverter.toDexFile(DexConverter.java:31)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexConversionEnqueuer$ClassToDex.call(DexConversionEnqueuer.java:173)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.dexer.DexConversionEnqueuer$ClassToDex.call(DexConversionEnqueuer.java:156)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Note in particular:

*invoking a static interface method java.util.stream.Collector.of:(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;Ljava/util/function/BinaryOperator;Ljava/util/
function/Function;[Ljava/util/stream/Collector$Characteristics;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector; strictly requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (**blocked at current API level 13**)*

Both `AndroidManifest.xml` files invovled specify `minSdkVersion=28` and `targetSdkVersion=28`.

II guess it's possible that `Collectors.of` is just not allowed in Android, but this seems odd as static interface methods and the Stream api are present for sufficiently high sdk versions.

UPDATE (20210131): Well, I thought I'd figured something out with a downgrade to v28.1, which was avoiding the use of `Collector.of` that seemed to be triggering the error.  This allowed me to build the android project but a lot of other code started to fail after being unable to find some code like `ImmutableList.toImmutableList()`.  Further experimentation revealed that a transitive dep was pulling in `v30-android` and this explained everything.  When I pinned to `v28.1` the other issues went away but the problem with referencing `Collector.of` came back (not surprising).

So I'm back to: Streams seem ok for android in general, as do static methdo interfacaes, but a reference to `Collector.of` blows things up and gives an error message referring to "API version 13".

---

As an aside/add-on question: I tried using the `--nodesugar_for_android` flag and, as expected, got errors like:

```
src\main\java\com\example1\bazel\MainActivity.java:26: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
```

oddly, when I tried also using the flag `--javacopt="-source 8"` (or "-source 8 -target 8) or using

```
javacopts = [
  "-source 8",
  "-target 8",
]
```

in either or both `BUILD` files, I continually got the same error, as though bazel was ignoring the directive to use `-source 8` even though that's what the error suggests.  That persisted until I cleaned out my WORKSPACE of all the cruft from prior experiments involving needing maven.  Once I did that the error message changed to:

```
src\main\java\com\example1\bazel\MainActivity.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    clickMeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> helloBazelTextView.setText(greeter.sayHello()));
                                     ^
  symbol:   method metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)
  location: interface LambdaMetafactory
Fatal Error: Unable to find method metafactory
T
```

A search for that led to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427655/cannot-find-symbol-method-metafactory-using-lambda) which references `core-lambda-stubs.jar`.  I verified that I do have this file (dated 2021-01-18) in my latest `build_tools` (30.0.3) folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [Guava docs](https://github.com/google/guava#guava-google-core-libraries-for-java) say that if you want to use Guava for Android, you'll have to use the `-android` artifact. The `-jre` version cannot be used as a dep for `android_*` rules.

To make `rules_jvm_external` work with it, you probably want to have two `maven_install` repos, unfortunately:

```
maven_install(
    # default maven repo
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.guava:guava:27.0-jre",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)

maven_install(
    name = "android_maven",
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

It helps to create aliases:

```
alias(
    name = "guava",
    target = "@maven//:com_google_guava_guava",
)

alias(
    name = "android_guava",
    target = "@android_maven//:com_google_guava_guava",
)
```

And then depend on `//package/to:guava` and `//package/to:android_guava` in your pure-Java and Android targets respectively.

Comment: Is there a way (other than creating a macro and having parallel build targets under he hood, or manually creating them) to then say "if you're building an android binary, use the `android_guava` target all the way down, otherwise use the normal one?

The goal is to not have to maintain separate android versions for anything that *might* be included in Android.  Especially since things are inconsistent as to what's allowed.  I Updated the Q to note that I was able to build with static interface methods that were added not through the Guava import.

Comment: If there really is no way, then I'll see what I can do.  My concern is that the error message I'm getting (and the other experiment with static interface methods) suggest that this *should* work as long as `minSdkVersion` is sufficiently high, which I have, but it dies anyway thinking (somewhere) that the version is only 13.