# FLUTTER Project Error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, macos, visual-studio-code

I have a Mac, and when I run Flutter application with VSCode on iPhone it works, but if I run the same application on Android phone then throw error

**Already Question But No Answer :**

[Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59509560/execution-failed-for-task-appdesugardebugfiledependencies)

**Visual Studio Error :**

https://prnt.sc/qrlvt1

**Android Studio Error :**

https://prnt.sc/qrlw6r

https://prnt.sc/qrlway

https://prnt.sc/qrlwfk

https://prnt.sc/qrlwkc

https://prnt.sc/qrlwpm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Android SDK manager to uninstall build tools 28, and then reinstall them. That worked for me.

The build tools are listed under the 'SDK Tools' tab, you have to uncheck 'Hide obsolete packages' and check 'Show package details' to show version 28 of the build tools.

https://prnt.sc/qrnv1b